# Can meta tag description be declared dynamically in a web page

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I have a dynamic page, where the contents and title will change based on the parameters in the URL.  I want the same to be done for meta tag description. As I don't have a sound knowledge of SEO, I don't know whether it will be valid or not.
Say suppose URL contains word **"test"**
I will do,

```
if("test" is present)
{
<title>test</test>
<meta decription="test"/>
}
else
{
<title>test1</test>
<meta decription="test1"/>

}
```

Can I do this? Does giving two meta tag descriptions for same page work.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to have different, **on the page content based** values of the `title` element and the `meta` description for each web page. It is not forbidden by the the HTML5 specification to have multiple `<meta name="description" content="YOUR DESCRIPTION">` elements but I would guess that search engines process only the first appearance of the element. So my recommendation would be use one `<meta name="description" content="YOUR DESCRIPTION">` element for each page.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you code it server-side (eg in PHP) when the page is generated rather than client-side (javascript) after the page has loaded, then it will be fine.   That's how most CMS systems work already.

Done server-side, only one of the description tags will actually appear in the code Google see.

Done client-side, it is likely that they will see no description at all as I don't think many search engines render javascript.